# Alternative to Python For Loop for faster results

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

Here’s my situation. I’m trying to build a huge database containing all the historical data (1/1/2017 to 6/30/2019) of NYSE & NASDAQ stocks and their indicators.

All the 4000+ stocks are stored in one table named “ALLSTOCKS”. This table is updated daily using my csv upload.

The csv download contains the open, high, low and close of each individual stocks which will be stored from their respective columns. From these numbers, my python code will automatically perform computation. A good example of these computations are getting the 9, 20, 50 and 100 day close averages.

To do this, i pull the last 9, 20, 50 and days CLOSE of each stock and do a simple mysql AVG() function and store it to the assigned column (MA9) from “ALLSTOCK” database.

I’ve mentioned that the stocks are 4000+ in total right? Therefore, i decided to enclosed the Average Formula in a FOR LOOP.

Here’s few of my code:

```
for ticker in tickers:

mycursor.execute("SELECT format(AVG(Close),4) from (select Close from _PSEI where stock = '" + ticker + "' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,9) _PSEI")
manine = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

mycursor.execute("SELECT format(AVG(Close),4) from (select Close from _PSEI where stock = '" + ticker + "' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,20) _PSEI")
matwenty = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Anyway, the problem is since this is a **for loop** with a variable array that contains 4000 plus items. I am getting a slow results. Meaning, my code executes for about .3 to .5 second each stock  and it will take 2000 seconds max before it finishes the entire loop.

Here's a (portion) of variable array:

```
ticker = ["CHK","BAC","GE","VALE","T","F","PFE","GGB","ECA","SWN","BBD","GME","RRC","FCX","AUY","AVP","APC","KGC","PBR","WFC","S","NBR","DB","C","SAN","KO","PG","RIG","HAL","MRK","X","NOK","APA","DNR","JPM","NLY","MRO","GFI","VZ","RF","XOM","NEM","NKE","HPQ","MS","CLF","DAL","SLB","M","ESV","V","KR","CTL","KEY","JCP","OXY","DIS","BP","CIG","EOG","IAG","MO","GM","RIO","EQT","GOL","HMY","ABB","DVN","MGM"]
```

Is there anyway to make it faster? Any fast approach that you can suggest? How would you do it if you have this kind of situation?

Comment: is it safe to assume that processing per ticker is not dependent on the results of processing on any other ticket? i.e. can these be done in parallel?

Comment: You could solve this with a SQL approach: grouping by ticker, instead of making one query for each ticker's value

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting this right but to start I want to asl. Are you reading your data as pandas DataFrame? Because there's a faster way to obtain columns using pandas, given a set of values to be used as your 'criteria' for the columns you just want to get.

Comment: @Joe No. im not using panda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taking so long because you're running a query (DB call) for each one of the 4000+ stocks.

I would try to run one query which checks all the stocks, for example:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT ... where stock in ('CHK', 'GE', 'BAC', ...) ...")
```

The trade off will be good because this one heavy query will be called only once (vs. ~4000 queries that are executed the way it's currently implemented).

In general, it's better performance-wise to make fewer calls to the DB (and bring more data in each call) then the other way around because the overhead for each call is big.

Comment: Don't you want to group by stock?

Comment: @josoler this is an example, I don't know how the business logic works here and it's definitely not the point of the question nor the answer.

Comment: I may be missing something, but won't your query return a single value? If so, it is indeed relevant to the answer, as one should expect the output to have as many values as in the for loop.

Comment: @josoler nope, it may return multiple records and the receiver will have to iterate the results. Again, the point is not the query itself but the fact that instead of building a query per stock we can run one query against _all_ the stocks. I added the query as an example to show that `stock in (...)` syntax may be used, but again - this is just an example!

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood your query then. I thought it would average the closing values through all the stocks wich may be misleading. Thanks!

Comment: hey @alfasin, thank you for your answer. i'll look into this within the day. Thanks again and have a great day. :)